# Sync google drive - without a client installation

Tags: windows, sync, google-drive

Is it possible to sync files between the Google drive files which are present in the local system (Windows 7) and the Google Drive servers? Normally we install the Google Drive client on our system which takes care of all the syncing. So you can keep editing your files locally inside the Google Drive Folder without worrying about them getting synced with your google account because the client will take care of it. However, due to certain restrictions on my system the Google Drive client cannot be installed.

One method to sync would be to open the Google Drive in my browser each time, download all the files locally, make changes, and then upload them again. However, this would be quite tedious. Is there any way to sync them without having to install the Google Drive client?

Comment: You can attach your Google drive as a windows share drive.  Why do you want to avoid the simply way?

Comment: @Ramhound Correct me if I'm wrong but if I mount the Google drive folder as a windows share drive then it will help people across the local subnet have access to my files. It won't help update the Google drive servers with my local files.

Comment: What?  That question is not clear

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what wasn't clear. Nevertheless I've updated my original post with more details. I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a solution to this.

Best I've found so far would be mapping the drive as a drive letter WITHOUT using "subst" that most of the online guides suggest.

The only solutions I've found for this are commercial. Netdrive, Expandrive, Webdrive etc.

When the Google drive is mounted as a drive letter, you can then use any standard sync tool of your choice (eg "synctool") to sync with your local drive's folders.